# Groovy expando metaclass

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, expandometaclass

I've developed a Class that has some methods that augment Integer, it mainly lets me do this:

```
def total = 100.dollars + 50.euros
```

Now I have to extend Integer.metaClass doing something like this:

```
Integer.metaClass.getDollars = {->
    Money.Dollar(delegate)
}
```

I tried putting that at the bottom of the file, before the Money class declaration, but the compiler says that a class Named Money already exists, I know why it happens (because groovy creates a class with the name of the file with an empty static void main to run this code).

I also tried using a static block inside the class like this:

```
static {
    Integer.metaClass.getDollars = {->
        Money.Dollar(delegate)
    }
}
```

This neither works.

A third solution would be to change the file name (like MoneyClass.groovy) and keep the class name (class Money) but that seems a bit weird.

Is there anything else I can do? Thanks.

Comment: Dang! I need to learn Groovy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it in any method of any class maybe a bean TypeEnhancer.groovy:

```
public class TypeEnhancer {
  public void start() {
    Integer.metaClass.getDollars() = {-> Money.Dollar(delegate) }
  }

  public void stop() {
    Integer.metaClass = null
  }
}
```

Just create and initalize by calling start(): `new TypeEnhancer().start();`.
To disable the enhancement, call `new TypeEnhancer().stop();`. The bean can also used as Spring bean.

Comment: thanks but I'd prefer not calling any strange method to initialize my expandos. Also doing metaClass = null might seem to create bugs later (groovy uses the metaClass field internaly).

Comment: metaClass = null is the recommended approach to remove all expandos, as Guillaume Laforge says two weeks ago, when i met him.